# Kivy TabbedPanel cutoff

Tags: python, kivy

I am learning how to create GUIs in Python using the Kivy library.
Currently stuck with a sizing issue.

I created a tabbed panel. However, it seems it gets cut off by the Windows top menu bar.

Is there a proper fix for this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KSj5.png)

Comment: You should share your code that produces this, it's likely that you didn't properly nest your content, or properly declare the size relationship to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between my example and yours is the __init__ method. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelHeader
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class designTab(TabbedPanel):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(designTab, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # self.tab_height = "40dp"
        # self.tab_width = "100dp"
        self.default_tab_text = "DESIGNS"
        self.do_default_tab = False
        self.content = BoxLayout()

    def addTab(self, design):
        newTab = TabbedPanelHeader(text=design)
        newTab.content = Label(text="Design Stuff")
        self.add_widget(newTab)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        tabObj = designTab()
        tabObj.addTab("design1")
        tabObj.addTab("design2")
        return tabObj


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I tried yours as well and it does the same thing.

I think it is with my environment. I tried it on another computer and it works just fine... 

Appreciate the help though. Thank you.